# POST PACH в 1С из JAVA/Аndroid

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, 1с

Пишу небольшое приложение под android для инвенторизации

Получаю данные из базы:

```java
@GET("/{database}/odata/standard.odata/Document_ИнвентаризацияТоваровНаСкладе")
public Call<Inventory> getInventoryOfGoods(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Path("database") String database, @Query("$format") String format, @Query("$select") String select,@Query("$orderby") String orderby);
```

```java
 public List<Inventory.Value> getInventory(){
        synchronized (lockInventory) {
            List<Inventory.Value> list = new ArrayList<Inventory.Value>();
            try {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(config.url)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                InventoryService service = retrofit.create(InventoryService.class);
                String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((config.login + ":" + config.password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                Call<Inventory> call = service.getInventory(auth, config.database, "json", "Ref_Key,Number,Комментарий,Date", "Date desc");
                Response<Inventory> userResponse = call.execute();
                Inventory inventory = userResponse.body();
                Log.d(TAG, "received collection size - " + inventory.getValue().size());
                for (Inventory.Value val : inventory.getValue()) {
                    list.add(val);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return list;
        }

    }
```

С этим проблем нет, а вот как построить @PACH или @POST запрос?
Буду признателен за любой пример обращение к 1С через @PACH или @POST не на языке 1С.

Comment: Ретрофит это сила) http://java-help.ru/retrofit-library/

Comment: @Valeriy пока никто не помог(что укрепило меня в мысле о жадности и корысти людей понимающих в 1с), вкурил маны ретрофита 
`@PATCH("/{database}/odata/standard.odata/Document_ИнвентаризацияТоваровНаСкладе(guid:'{guid}')")
    public Call<OrderForGoods> sendOrderForGoods(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Path("database") String database, @Path("guid") String guid, @Query("$format") String format, @Body ForSend forSend);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@PATCH("/{database}/odata/standard.odata/Document_ИнвентаризацияТоваровНаСкладе(guid:'{guid}')") 
public Call<OrderForGoods> sendOrderForGoods(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Path("database") String database, @Path("guid") String guid,@Query("$format") String format, @Body ForSend forSend);
```